Access cookies in Maui Blazor Hybrid App?
I have a .NET 8 Maui Blazor Hybrid App, in which I'm currently trying to figure out how to get access to cookies from a BlazorWebView.
So far I've checked the WebView documentation, which has the "Cookies" property that I'd need. But, despite the name, BlazorWebView is curiously not derived from WebView.
One way I've found to get access to the webview that at least has members regarding cookies is via platform-specific code, abusing the actual implementation behind the BlazorWebView. For Windows this would look like this:
MainPage.xaml.cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    var webView = blazorWebView.Handler?.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
}

However, if I then try to get the CookieManager from that WebView2, I run into a nullref
//CoreWebView2 is null here
var cm = webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager;

Another issue with this is that the result would be a CoreWebview2CookieManager, managing a list of CoreWebView2Cookie, not nice and simple System.Net Cookies. Which means that not just getting the cookies, but every class that then touches the cookies has to also be implemented for each platform.
I understand that I could just use IPreferences or ISecureStorage instead of cookies, and do auth via AuthenticationStateProvider, but I can't believe that there would not be some easy access to cookies from a BlazorWebView like there is from a regular WebView. Is there really not?


However, if I then try to get the CookieManager from that WebView2, I run into a nullref

This is because the BlazorWebview is not initialized when the Page's OnHandlerChanged method excuted.
You can try to get the CookieManager in the BlazorWebview' BlazorWebViewInitialized method:
In the xaml:
<BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html" BlazorWebViewInitialized="blazorWebView_BlazorWebViewInitialized">

And in the code behind:
private void blazorWebView_BlazorWebViewInitialized(object sender, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.BlazorWebViewInitializedEventArgs e)
 {
     var webview = blazorWebView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView2;
     var webView2 = webview.CoreWebView2;
     var cookie = webView2.CookieManager;
 }

And as you see, there is no cookie property for the BlazorWebview, you need to access it by calling platform native code.

Bit late on my part, but I finally got around to trying this and it does get me the cookie manager. Platform-specific code for cookie handling is a dealbreaker in my case so I've since accepted my fate and do it with js. Thank you very much for you answer though, learned something.
